# Visual Studio Find all references ignores var

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I want to find all references to some class in visual studio but instances defined with var are ignored.

Is there some way to fix this?

Here i am using SHIFT+F12 to get references

[image: SHIFT+F12]

The results are:

[image]

But when using ReportWindow on line 1197:
[image]

I get what i want

[image]

Comment: This should add tag "C#".

Comment: It is just a textual search - C# __var__ and C++ __auto__ are just for convenient coding.  Textual searches do not know the context so they are unable to work it out.  If it appears in a template, VS won't find it either.  VS is slow enough: adding contextual searches would make it even slower.

Comment: Too bad I hoped there was some plugin for this

Comment: Try `ReSharper`

Comment: `Is there some way to fix this?` - yes. Don't use `var` :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At this point in time, VS 2015, 2017 and 2019 have this behaviour for the built-in *Find All References* search, as well as Resharper's *Find Usages* and *Find Usages Advanced* search options. It is also expected behaviour.

The only time a `var` reference will be returned in the search results is when you make an explicit call to a constructor. Also, when a method is called and returned to variable that has been explicitly declared as the given type, that line will also be returned in the search results.

Personally, I like to use `var` only when it is obvious what is being returned and assigned to a variable, which is usually only when a constructor is called directly. This is also handy when declaring a class with a long and inconvenient name, avoiding having to *type that type* twice:

```
Dictionary<string, Ninja> trainees = new Dictionary<string, Ninja>();
```

Here is an example of a small program demonstrating where *Find All References* will find results and where it will not.

```
using System;
​
namespace VarSearchTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var ninja = NinjaAcademy.Train();     // <---------- does not find (implicit)
            Ninja ninja2 = NinjaAcademy.Train();  // <---------- finds (explicit type declaration)
            var chrisFarley = new Ninja();        // <---------- finds (explicit constructor call)


            Console.WriteLine(ninja.Hide());
            Console.WriteLine(ninja2.Hide());
            Console.WriteLine(chrisFarley.Hide());
        }
    }
​
    public class Ninja  // <-------------------- Find all references/usages
    {
        public string Hide()
        {
            return "Puff of smoke...";
        }
    }
​
    public static class NinjaAcademy
    {
        public static Ninja Train()  // <---------------- finds (explicit return type)
        {
            return new Ninja();      // <------------------ finds (explicit constructor call)
        }
    }
}
```

You can also track [this github issue](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/issues/24905) in case it ever changes in the future, as it would be handy to have implicit references easy to find. In the meantime, consider using `var` only in the scenarios where it provides convenience in the explicit situations.